# Notify Adapter, Activity/Fragment, or POJO to receive realtime messages from API (Retrofit)?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, retrofit, sendmessage

I am confused to notfity my adapter class to get messages at realtime like Whatsapp or any other messenger. I am getting messages from the server but only if I refresh my activity, not getting messages without refreshing so how can I notify and update my adapter or activity to get messages at realtime like messengers without refreshing or reopening my activity.
example: I am sending a message from my emulator and receiving it on my phone in ChatActivity, I just want to receive that sent message in my ChatActivity while it is open in my phone without refreshing or reopening my activity.
Thanks is advance.....

My Adapter Class:

```
public class ChatAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

    private static final int VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_SENT = 1;
    private static final int VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_RECEIVED = 2;
    ArrayList<Messages> mMessageList;
    Context mContext;

    public ChatAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Messages> messageList) {
        mContext = context;
        mMessageList = messageList;
    }

    // Inflates the appropriate layout according to the ViewType.
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.@NotNull ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NotNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view;

        if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_SENT) {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.row_send_message, parent, false);
            return new SentMessageHolder(view);
        } else if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_RECEIVED) {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.row_received_message, parent, false);
            return new ReceivedMessageHolder(view);
        }

        return null;
    }

    // Determines the appropriate ViewType according to the sender of the message.
    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        Messages message = mMessageList.get(position);

        if (message.getSendby().equals("user")) {
            // If the current user is the sender of the message
            return VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_SENT;
        } else {
            // If some other user sent the message
            return VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_RECEIVED;
        }
    }

    // Passes the message object to a ViewHolder so that the contents can be bound to UI.
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Messages message = mMessageList.get(position);

        switch (holder.getItemViewType()) {
            case VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_SENT:
                ((SentMessageHolder) holder).bind(message);
                break;
            case VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_RECEIVED:
                ((ReceivedMessageHolder) holder).bind(message);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mMessageList.size();
    }


    static class SentMessageHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        @BindView(R.id.txtSendMessage)
        TextView txtSendMessage;

        SentMessageHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
        }

        void bind(Messages message) {
            txtSendMessage.setText(message.getMessages());
        }
    }

    static class ReceivedMessageHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        @BindView(R.id.text_gchat_message_other)
        TextView text_gchat_message_other;

        ReceivedMessageHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
        }

        void bind(Messages message) {
            text_gchat_message_other.setText(message.getMessages());

        }
    }}
```

ChatActivity:
OnClick to send messages:

```
public void sendMessage(View view) {
        try {
            message = etMessage.getText().toString();

            Api.getClient().sendMessage(bookingID, userId, providerId, message).enqueue(new Callback<ArrayList<Messages>>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(@NotNull Call<ArrayList<Messages>> call, @NotNull Response<ArrayList<Messages>> response) {
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        etMessage.setText("");
                        getMessageList();
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NotNull Call<ArrayList<Messages>> call, @NotNull Throwable t) {
                    Toast.makeText(ChatActivity.this, "" + t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
```

ChatActivity:
getting list of messages(messages history):

```
 private void getMessageList() {
        loading.show();
        Api.getClient().getMessageList(bookingID).enqueue(new Callback<ArrayList<Messages>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NotNull Call<ArrayList<Messages>> call, @NotNull Response<ArrayList<Messages>> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    chatAdapter = new ChatAdapter(ChatActivity.this, response.body());
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(chatAdapter);
                    loading.dismiss();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NotNull Call<ArrayList<Messages>> call, @NotNull Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(ChatActivity.this, "" + t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

onCreate():

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        getWindow().setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_background));
        loading = MyUtils.getLoadingDialog(this);
        bookingID = getIntent().getIntExtra("bookingId", 0);
        userId = getIntent().getIntExtra("userId", 0);
        providerId = getIntent().getIntExtra("providerId", 0);
        getMessageList();
    }
```

Comment: why are you creating new adapters for sending and getting each time ? create one adapter, set it to your recycler. when new data comes in, clear out the old data in the adapter, give it the new data, notify your adapter

Comment: Hi there, This is how my API is created. One adapter is for Temporary chat during chatting and another one is for message history and where should I implement clear and update of adapter?

Comment: both times you're making use of `ChatAdapter` so i don't see how this makes a difference ?

Comment: Where do you call getMessageList() method?

Comment: in onCreate getMessageList();

Comment: @a_local_nobody, thanks you were right about calling same adapter in SendMessage(), now I have updated my code kindly check this out and please help me!

Comment: nothing i said has changed :) make one adapter. when you retrieve new data, clear out the old data in the adapter, give it the new data, notify adapter to change

Comment: @a_local_nobody where should I implement clear, add and notify?

Comment: @CreativeZaidi If you want to get data from your api and update list constantly, you should call getMessageList() method in loop. Search about pulling polling. Or search about fcm

Comment: `where should I implement clear, add and notify` well, think about it. where are you getting new data ? that would be inside onResponse, right ?

Comment: @a_local_nobody I am sending a message from my emulator and receiving it on my phone in ChatActivity, I just want to receive that sent message in my ChatActivity while it is open in my phone without refreshing or reopening my activity.

Comment: @CreativeZaidi Kotlin Coroutine Live Data would be the best solution to handle this problem in modern programming. Do you wish to use Kotlin ?

Comment: @NRUSINGHAMOHARANA but I am a Java developer how can I do that in Java?

Comment: @CreativeZaidi Well , this also can be done using Java. Have you used Live Data ?

Comment: @NRUSINGHAMOHARANA nope can you please guide me regarding LiveData?

Comment: well, my problem is solved by using Handler every after 1 second but I don't think its an efficient way to do this, do you guys have any efficient way?

Comment: @CreativeZaidi  Using handler is a immediate solution for your problem. But it would be better if you follow modern standards, like Live Data, DiffUtil etc.                                            https://medium.com/@guendouz/room-livedata-and-recyclerview-d8e96fb31dfe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44489235/update-recyclerview-with-android-livedata

Comment: Thanks guys for your help, Special thanks for you @NRUSINGHAMOHARANA